# php request input text populated by jquery $.post

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form where there are some inputs text that are populated by a jquery $.post function, when I request the values, I don't get nothing.

Inputs are between `<form>` and `</form>`. 
I'm doing a simply `$_REQUEST['nameOfInput']` that will give its value.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the `$.post`

Comment: are you sure you have form tag wrapped around the input controls

Comment: $.post('some.php', {'id': id}, function (txt) {
                               $('.input').html(txt); 
});

Comment: yes, inputs are wrapped around form tag

Comment: where are you posting? can you plz share the code for markup and js?

Comment: Where do you get `id` from?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`.

And make sure that the values are passed properly to the JQuery function!

Comment: Try doing `$.post('some.php',{'id': id},function(data){ $('.input').val(data);});`

Answer (score 0):

If your code is exactly `$.post('some.php',{'id': id},function(txt){ $('.input').html(txt);});` the problem is in your function(txt), you are using the class selector $('.input') whereas your inputs are DOM elements, so the right selector is $('input').
Then your code should be `$.post('some.php',{'id': id},function(txt){ $('input').html(txt);});`